# Estimation of Maximum Heap Size PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, heap-size

I want to estimate my maximum heap size in PyCharm for a full-stack App.
How can one get a sophisticated first good guess? Of course it depends on the specific application but can I get something like an upper boundary as an result of the used packages, libraries, etc.?

I found on several pages hints like this on the page of IBM: > To optimize application performance and keep within the 40 - 70% range, the maximum heap size setting should therefore be at least 43% larger than the maximum occupancy of the application < Yet, this doesn't solve the problem of how big my load will probably be.

I could of course try to get a good guess by the task manager on checking what the occupancy during the crash has been. However this seems rather cumbersome to me.

Is it maybe also possible to allocate it rather dynamically without any boundary?

Thanks in advance